# How set default value to Mui DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

i got issue with set default value of DatePicker. This is a component for edit object, so, when page is render, all controllers defaultValues are those acquired from the object that you select in the previous component.

I have this atributte on my object:

`estimated_close_date: '15-02-2024'`

My useEffect where i setValue of all Controllers

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getOptionTools()
    for (const key in defaultValuesEdit) {
      setValue(key, defaultValuesEdit[key])
    }
  }, [editProblem, setValue])
```

DatePicker

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
  <Typography>Estimacion de Cierre</Typography>
    <Controller
       name="estimated_close_date"
       control={control}
       rules={{ required: true }}
       render={({ field }) => (
         <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale={'en-gb'}>
            <DatePicker
               slotProps={{ textField: { size: 'small' } }}
               onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)} />
             </LocalizationProvider>
          )}>
    </Controller>
</Grid>
```

I tried convert estimated_close_date with dayjs, but dosen't work.

---

I tried with this:

```
const defaultValuesEdit = editProblem ? {
    name: editProblem.name,
    description: editProblem.description,
    tools: editProblem.tools,
    type: editProblem.type,
    estimated_close_date: dayjs(editProblem.estimated_close_date)
  } : defaultValues
```

but format dayjs is MM/DD/YYYY and also with config dayjs to DatePicker, this dosen't work to